# Remove an element from List A, Compare a list A and an String Array B and remove elements from array B, which are in List A,

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list and a String array

```
String[] B
List<String> A
```

I want to checkif an element exists in List A, remove it,
and then remove elements in array B, which are in list A,

How can it be done in Java 8 using streams, in a single line ?

This is how how remve the element from List
A.stream().filter(element -> !element.equalsIgnoreCase(tobeIgnored).collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: added an example

Comment: Do you want remove *all* elements of list A from array B, or just remove the specified element from array B if it exists in list A?

Comment: #1 remove element from list A, if it matches a condition, then  if any element of array B is in list A, remove that from array B,

Comment: Those are two separate, independent tasks. Why do you expect to do both of these things in a single line?

Comment: no special reasons, was thinking if i can combine these two codes...

Answer (score 1):

First of all I'd create a `HashSet` from `A` and a List from the array:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(B));
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(A);
```

And than create the array with only the elements you want:

```
list.removeIf(set::contains);
list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

seems this is working:

```
List A
Array B

B = Arrays.stream(B).filter(s -> !(A.stream().filter(el ->  
!el.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")).collect(Collectors.toList())). 
contains(s)).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: I hope I never see this sort of code in production! But that's not the fault of the code: it meets the strange requirements, and does so quite nicely!

Comment: i agree , its not readable, i probably wouldn't do that as well !

Comment: Apart from being almost unreadable, this uses `contains` over a list, which is `O(N^2)`. And all this because of the desire to write two separate tasks in one line...